# send docx files using curl php

Tags: php, docusignapi

i am using the rest api for docusign.

i am sending a document to another user for online signing. What is happening in the code is that the document is being uploaded and the contents of the file is being read using the file_get_contents function and then using curl this content is sent to the other user through docusign.

Here is my code:

```
$data = "{
  \"emailBlurb\":\"\",
  \"emailSubject\":\"DocuSign API - Please Sign This Document...\",
  \"documents\":[
    {
      \"documentId\":\"1\",
      \"name\":\"agreement.pdf\"
    }
  ],
  \"recipients\":{
    \"signers\":[
      {
        \"email\":\"$email\",
        \"name\":\"$name\",
        \"recipientId\":\"1\",
        \"tabs\":{
          \"signHereTabs\":[
            {
              \"xPosition\":\"100\",
              \"yPosition\":\"100\",
              \"documentId\":\"1\",
              \"pageNumber\":\"1\"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  \"status\":\"sent\"
}";  

$file_contents = file_get_contents("uploads/envelopes/" . $file_name);

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\”document.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

// *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {

    $msg = 'Error. Please try again';

}
```

**The above code is working fine for pdf files but not for docx files.**

For docx files, i have changed the code like this (changed the content type):

```
$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\”document.docx\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";
```

Thanks

Comment: Paste the full code that doesn't work; for all we know your `$data` is wrong. Also what's the error that the service returns?

Comment: Did you try to contact the commercial support of DocuSign? you know they provide support to their customers and sample for their REST API? (yes I know this doesn't directly help with his problem, but it seems that he is asking something that a company who owns the product and supports it should provide)

Comment: Another anecdote, where did you see that DocuSign supports DOCX?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does support sending .docx files, so file format is not causing your issue.  Are you receiving a specific error message when you attempt to send a .docx file?  If so, then what's the error?

FWIW, I'm able to send a .docx file via the DocuSign REST API -- I've included my full request below. If possible, I'd suggest that you use Fiddler (or any similar utility) to produce a trace of the full request that you're sending to the server, and compare its contents/structure with the (successful) example request that I've included below. Doing so would hopefully allow you to identify (and resolve) the problem with your request.

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER/envelopes HTTP/1.1

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"USERNAME","Password":"PASSWORD","IntegratorKey":"INTEGRATOR_KEY"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 15384

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "status" : "sent",
    "emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
    "emailSubject": "-- Test Email Subject --",
    "documents": [
    {
        "name": "CustomerAgreement.docx",
        "documentId": 1
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers" : [{
            "email": "bobsemail@outlook.com",
            "name": "Bob Adamson",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                {
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "tabLabel": "Customer_Signature",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "xPosition": "99",
                    "yPosition": "424"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Content-Disposition: file; filename="CustomerAgreement.docx"; documentid="1"

<document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
```